# Error CA0053 with Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, sonarqube-5.0

Getting this error while running VSSonarExtension:

```
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\dataflowrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\designrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\globalizationrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\interoperabilityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\maintainabilityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\mobilityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\namingrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\performancerules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\portabilityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\reliabilityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\securityrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\securitytransparencyrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\usagerules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly
  'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\team tools\static analysis tools\
  fxcop\rules\securitytransparencyrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
MSBUILD : error : Code Analysis detected errors.
  See Code Analysis results window or log file for details.
  1081 Warning(s) 15 Error(s)
  Time Elapsed 00:00:41.66 
  [CxxSonarQubeMsbuidRunner] Failed to build project, check log in .cxxresults\BuildLog.txt
```

[People are saying](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-fix-the-ca0053-error-in-code-analysis-in.aspx) it's due to the fact that the project was created on previous VS versions (I am using VS2013). The error is related to FxCop. Does anyone know how to fix it and get the report from VSSonarExtension? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out - the error was indeed caused by the fact that the projects were created on earlier versions of VisualStudio. A fix from [this website](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-fix-the-ca0053-error-in-code-analysis-in.aspx) helps significantly - I have checked out my solution, placed the [CA0053 Fix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/471da13b-d415-4a44-a4e9-a8222316b902?tduid=(4b094eaa69af6014f988d07e839764bb)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-J2LQ_TdNkPu6sWOZfSBqHA)()) file in the folder with the solution, made sure that files (specifically all of the .csproj files) are NOT read-only, and ran the tool. That seemed to have fixed the issue.